# iPhone MIMChartLib Chart Drawing: How can i set the Y-axis starting from 18000 but not 0?

Tags: iphone, ios, charts, drawing

I am now using **MIMChartLib to developer Iphone Chart,**
But i am having trouble about the line chart,

for example 
here is my CSV

`Time;NAME;value001;value002;value003;value004;
01:00.0;ABCABC;1837;1837.2;1836.5;1831
02:00.0;ABCABC;1836.7;1837;1836.5;1836.7
03:00.0;ABCABC;1827;1827.2;1816.5;1826.9
04:00.0;ABCABC;1837;1837.2;1836.5;1836.9
05:00.0;ABCABC;1837;1837.2;1836.5;1836.9`

How can i set the Y axis to be 18000, but not start from zero.
otherwise,the chart will show really really small.

here is [preview](http://www.nullmicgi.com/question.png):

here is my code
    /*
     Date;Time;Currency;Bid;Ask
     14/9/2011;00:03.0;LLGUSD;1836.5;1837

```
 */


[MIMColor InitColors];
NSString *csvPath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myTableBar.csv"];    
//LineGraph *lineGraph=[[LineGraph alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 20, 220, 380)];
LineGraph *lineGraph=[[LineGraph alloc]initWithFrame:Chartarea.frame];
lineGraph.needStyleSetter=YES;
lineGraph.xIsString=YES; 
lineGraph.anchorType=CIRCLEBORDER; //OTHER anchorType
[lineGraph readFromCSV:csvPath1 titleAtColumn:1 valueInColumn:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"3", nil]];
[lineGraph displayYAxis];
[lineGraph displayXAxisWithStyle:5]; //OTHER styles FOR X-Axis Labels
[lineGraph drawWallGraph];

[self.view addSubview:lineGraph];
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
go this link

https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library

in YAxisBand.m file u have this method it work for me.....


-(void)setScaleForYTile:(float)value  withNumOfLines:(int)numOfHorLines
{
    pixelPerYTile=18000000.0;
    //pixelPerYTile=value;
    HorLines=numOfHorLines;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Comment: I have already download this pack of file, but i want to change the start point from 18000 but not from zero

Answer (score 0):

go this link
[https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library](http://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library)

```
In MIMLineGraph.m
```

go to the function      `-(void)_findScaleForYTile`

and REMOVE the following code

```
 minOfY=[MIM_MathClass getMinFloatValue:[_yValElements objectAtIndex:0]];
    for (int i=1; i<[_yValElements count]; i++) 
    {
        float minOfY1=[MIM_MathClass getMinFloatValue:[_yValElements objectAtIndex:i]];
        if(minOfY1<minOfY)
            minOfY=minOfY1;
    }
```

and set the value of minOfY directly as zero instead of doing the above calculation

```
minOfY = 18000000.0;
```

NOTE: in MIMChartLib minimum value plotted in yaxis will be the smallest value that you give in CSV file for plotting..so if u need to start yaxis from 18000000.0 then if the minimum value in your CSV file is the same then MIMCHART will automatically set the starting value of yaxis as 18000000.0